# Call Salesforce API Rest with python

Tags: rest, apexrest, python

I'm try to call a REST web-service I made on Salesforce from a Python script

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test_rest_api')

global with sharing class Test_RestAPI {

    @HttpPost
    global static void postFeed(String s){

       //my code
       //
    }
}
```

The first par of my script is identification and work well

the second part give me an error 400 Bad Request

```
def callapipost(self):
        ## Create URL
        urlpost = https://test.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/test_rest_api        
##Create Header
        headerpost = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.bearer, 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        print('url utilisee ' + urlpost)
        ## create full request
        req = urllib.request.Request(url=urlpost, data=bytes(urllib.parse.urlencode(
                {
                    "s": "Test"
                }),
                'UTF-8'),
            headers=headerpost)

        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req):
                print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')
                print('OK ! ')
                print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')

        except urllib.error.HTTPError as er:
            print(er.msg)
            raise er

    def run(self):
        self.authSF()
        self.callapipost()


SendToSFAPI = SendToSFAPI()

try:
    SendToSFAPI.run()
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err :
    print(err)
```

raise err

When I try acces this WS with WorkBench, I have no problem

[image: des]

Is there something I miss here?

Comment: Could be a firewall issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload should **not** be urlencoded. `application/json` expects literal JSON. The request should look like this over the wire:

```
POST /services/apexrest/test_rest_api HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.my.salesforce.com
Content-Length: 12
Authorization: Bearer MySessionIdWouldBeHere
Content-Type: application/json

{"s":"Test"}
```

My Python is a little rusty, so you'll have to adjust your code appropriately, but simply removing the url-encoding part should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm @sfdcfox, JSON should not be urlencoded. Was following some exemple using urllib and I don't think this is the best function to do REST POST call to Salesforce (from this little experience, I may be wrong)

I used requests.request in my case to do it work :

```
myJson = { 's': 'Test' }
myHeader = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.bearer, 'Content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request('post', headers=myHeader, url=myInstanceSalesforce+'/services/apexrest/test_rest_api', json=myJson )
```